# Batch file to find the string and copy the next string to a new file

Tags: batch-file

I want to know how to write a batch script to find a string in a text file and copy the next string of it.

For Example:

Minimum Server Time:                31536000.000 sec

The batch script should write 31536000.000 in new file

Comment: i was able to get the entire line by finding a string
findstr /l "user" input.txt >> "newfile.txt"

Comment: Give a writing a `for /f` loop and with that `findstr` command and it should work

Comment: Example please,i am new to batch scripting !

Comment: in the output of `for /?` take a look at `tokens` and `delims`

Comment: check this site out for `for` loops: http://judago.webs.com/batchforloops.htm